# Delete all options in select list except third

Tags: jquery

The title says it all.

HTML:

```
<li class="mfieldtype_mnumber" id="modFilterField_29">
<label>From:</label>
<span class="filterinput">
<select size="1" class="inputbox text_area" name="cf29_2">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">COM_MTREE_EXACTLY</option>
<option value="2">COM_MTREE_MORE_THAN</option>
<option value="3">COM_MTREE_LESS_THAN</option>
</select>
<input type="text" placeholder="" size="30" class="inputbox text_area" name="cf29"></span></li>
```

I tried using the following code and implementing :not(nth-child) but I cant get it to work.

```
$('li#modFilterField_29 select')
    .find('option')
    .remove();
```

So to sum up, get rid of all options except the third (and NOT through using its value)

Help?

Comment: get the third . delete all and add the third !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var options = $('#modFilterField_29 select').find("option");
var keepOption = options.eq(2);
options.not(keepOption).remove();
```

1. This gets all the options.
2. Then, isolates the 2nd one.
3. Then removes the 2nd one from the list of all the options and removes the rest.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/JAxQu/

Or, if you want it fewer lines, you can do this:

```
var options = $('#modFilterField_29 select').find("option");
options.not(options.eq(2)).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use these combined Sizzle selectors:

```
$('#modFilterField_29 option:not(:nth-child(3))').remove();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dYHAf/1/)

- [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)
- [`:nth-child()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)